# Urlencode automating form

Tags: python, urlencode

I am trying to automate filling out a form on a website. I insert this data through a data parameter for urlencode. The from works fine for non-anonymous posts. I am trying to automate unchecking the "ask anonymously" button. The code that automates posts is below. It works fine for anonymous posts

The headers are not listed below for privacy reasons

```
Data = urllib.urlencode({'authenticity_token':'l/TOKEN=',     'question[question_text]': question1,'question[force_anonymous]': 'false'})
req  = urllib2.Request(url + "/questions/create", data=Data, headers=Headers)
res  = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = BeautifulSoup(res.read())
```

I am trying to add the parameter "unchecked" for the fields below. Right now I have the parameter 'question[force_anonymous]': 'false' (as you can see above) but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. The Ask anonymously button is checked on for its default.

```
<div class="questionType_box">
          <label class="typeCheckbox_text" for="question_force_anonymous">Ask anonymously</label>
          <input name="question[force_anonymous]" type="hidden" /><input checked="checked" class="typeCheckbox" id="question_force_anonymous" name="question[force_anonymous]" type="checkbox" value="force_anonymous" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated the format of data sent out from your target website? If not, you can do it such as:

1. install and open Chrome
2. go to your target website
3. open Developer tools (in Windows, shortcut is F12)
4. go to tab "Network", enable "Record Network Log" (the first button)
5. submit form through website
6. then the requests sent out from the website were recorded. Probably it would be a POST request. Check the form-data of the request